# Bluetooth no longer working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Turned Bluetooth off but can't turn back on)

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, hardware, firmware, bluez

**tl;dr I turned Bluetooth off and it wont turn back on.**

I've been running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for about six months and Bluetooth has been working flawlessly. I have been using Bluetooth with a Logitech M555b mouse without any problems. I recently purchased another Bluetooth mouse (Logitech T630) and after successfully setting it up it was extremely laggy and erratic.

**I turned Bluetooth off and it will NOT turn back on.** (I turned it off using the toggle switch under System Settings > Bluetooth) I've spent the last two days trying to turn my Bluetooth back on to no avail.

The Bluetooth icon has disappeared from the top menubar and will not come back. I have tried to turn the Bluetooth back on using the toggle found under System Settings > Bluetooth and at first it would switch to 'on' and turn orange but the menu icon wouldn't return and upon closing Settings and reopening it, it would be back in the 'off' position.

This behaviour was occuring when my Bluetooth was still showing up under "rfkill list all" as "hci0" (there were no soft blocks). Now it does not show up at all under 'rfkill list all' and all options under System Settings > Bluetooth including the toggle switch are greyed-out.

Things I have tried:

- 'sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart'
- 'sudo modprobe btusb'
- 'reinstalling all Bluetooth related packages via Synaptic
- 'rfkill unblock hci0' (When Bluetooth was showing up under 'rfkill list all', even though there were no soft blocks, but 'hci0' no longer shows up under 'rfkill list all'
- 'rfkill unblock all'
- 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez'
- 'sudo hciconfig hci0 reset' & 'sudo hciconfig hci0 up' (When hci0 was still showing up, hci0 has disappeared now)
- 'sudo service bluetooth stop' & 'sudo service bluetooth start'
- installing the package 'bluetooth'
- installing the package 'blueman' (running this application did temporarily restore the bluetooth icon in the menu bar, but none of its options worked)
- 'sudo mv /etc/bluetooth /etc/bluetooth.backup'
- many, many reboots and shutdowns

I've read through dozens of bluetooth-problems-in-ubuntu related links and nothing has worked. I dont believe this is a duplicate. These are some of the links I've tried to find a solution from:

- askubuntu.com/questions/286834/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04
- ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324071
- ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219575
- askubuntu.com/questions/758778/ubuntu-15-10-bluetooth-no-adapters-found?noredirect=1&lq=1
- askubuntu.com/questions/474839/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04
- askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800
- ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1546007

and many more but its not letting post links because im new to the site.

Here are some various outputs:

$ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0032 SiGma Micro 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:0161 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

$ rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0032 SiGma Micro 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:0161 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

$ "hciconfig -a"
returns nothing

$ lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bluetooth             520192  0
xt_multiport           16384  2
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              24576  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               36864  3 ip_tables,xt_multiport,iptable_filter
input_leds             16384  0
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               454656  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
arc4                   16384  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
iwlmvm                311296  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_ssm4567        16384  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_ssm4567
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
serio_raw              16384  0
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 36864  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
dw_dmac                16384  0
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
elan_i2c               36864  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
8250_dw                16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1208320  4
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
drm                   364544  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
e1000e                237568  0
ahci                   36864  4
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
libahci                32768  1 ahci
alx                    36864  0
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
mdio                   16384  1 alx
video                  40960  1 i915
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0
```

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep blue; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b]
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection I217-V [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0032 SiGma Micro 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:0161 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             520192  0
[    2.142805] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.146406] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1658.082516] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[ 1658.082530] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1658.082533] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1658.082535] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1658.082538] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

Thanks for any help provided, Bluetooth was working two days ago and I'm desperate to get it working again.